# How many elements in $X$ are of the form $3k + 1$ for some integer $k$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider the set $X={300,301,302,...,29999,30000}$ (the set of all integers from $300$ to $30,000$ inclusive.) You do not need to simplify the numeric answers.

How many elements in $X$ are of the form $3k + 1$ for some integer $k$?

One friend says the answer is $7425$ and another said $9900$, but I'm not sure how either got that or if either is correct.

I'm not quite sure how to do this problem. Initially I thought it was asking how many numbers are odd, or in the form $2k+1$ (the definition of an odd integer), but after looking at it again it's asking in the form $3k+1$. I know a number like $301$ is in that form $(3(100)+1)$, but how would I do it for the entire set? Thank you.

Comment: Seems exactly the same as the question you asked 1 hr before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 
$$\frac{30000}{3} = 10000$$
the largest number of the form $3k + 1$ that is in the set $X$ is $29998 = 3 \cdot 9999 + 1$.  Since 
$$\frac{300}{3} = 100$$
the largest number of the form $3k + 1$ that is not in the set $X$ is $298 = 3 \cdot 99 + 1$.  Thus, there are $9999 - 99 = 9900$ numbers in the set $X$ that are of the form $3k + 1$.

Answer (score 1):

So we have the set $\{300, 301, 302, \cdots, 29998, 29999, 30000\}$. NOte that the minimum and maximum values that are multiple of 3 are 300 and 30000 respectively.

The previous multiple of 3 from 30000 is 29997.

Since any integer of the form $3n+1$ is just immediately next integer to $3n$ so we have to find out how many integers are there in the sequence $\{301, \cdots, 29998\}$. As you can see it is an A.P. with first term 3, last term 29997 and the common difference is 3.

Can you make it out now?